# How to set a tkinter's window geometry for auto adaptation to space occupied by widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, widget, dimension

The question say everything. So, How can I affect the geometry of a window adapting its dimension to the space occupied by widgets?

Comment: Don't specify the geometry as long as no `.place()` is used on widgets.

Comment: But if I don't specify geometry, the window opens very little. It is the case of the root window where there are all the cascade menus. In this way, they are unreadable until I resize manually the window.

Comment: If you use `pack()` or `grid()` to place those widgets, it will adjust the window size automatically if `geometry()` is not called.

Comment: The default behavior when using `pack` and `grid` will always cause the window to auto-size. This is one of  tkinter's strengths. It's not really clear why you're asking this question.

Comment: Because I am a beginner, that's would be clear. Why anyone on StackOverflow won't understand that this platform is used also by noobs?